# Как использовать Plugin_Upgrader для WP?

Tags: wordpress

Хочу обновлять свой небольшой плагин удаленно. Что касается самого механизма обновления набросал код.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader-skin.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php' );

$plugin_file = 'путь/имя';

$skin = new \WP_Upgrader_Skin();
$upgrader = new \Plugin_Upgrader($skin);
$upgrader->upgrade($plugin_file);
```

Ругается на WP_Upgrader_Skin. Подскажите пожалуйста что добавить/исправить